# Error - reverted with reason string 'LOK'

Tags: solidity, transactions, tokens, contract-debugging

i got "`reverted with reason string 'LOK'`" error when executing this code (on the 'router.exactInputSingle(params)' exactly ) , why and how to fix this error ?;

```
contract UniswapV3FlashSwap {
ISwapRouter constant router =
    ISwapRouter(0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564);

uint160 internal constant MIN_SQRT_RATIO = 4295128739;
uint160 internal constant MAX_SQRT_RATIO =
    1461446703485210103287273052203988822378723970342;

// Example WETH/USDC
// Sell WETH high      -> Buy WETH low        -> WETH profit
// WETH in -> USDC out -> USDC in -> WETH out -> WETH profit
function flashSwap(
    address pool0,
    uint24 fee1,
    address tokenIn,
    address tokenOut,
    uint amountIn
) external {
    bool zeroForOne = tokenIn < tokenOut;
    uint160 sqrtPriceLimitX96 = zeroForOne
        ? MIN_SQRT_RATIO + 1
        : MAX_SQRT_RATIO - 1;
    bytes memory data = abi.encode(
        msg.sender,
        pool0,
        fee1,
        tokenIn,
        tokenOut,
        amountIn,
        zeroForOne
    );

    IUniswapV3Pool(pool0).swap(
        address(this),
        zeroForOne,
        int(amountIn),
        sqrtPriceLimitX96,
        data
    );
}

function uniswapV3SwapCallback(
    int amount0,
    int amount1,
    bytes calldata data
) external {
    (
        address caller,
        address pool0,
        uint24 fee1,
        address tokenIn,
        address tokenOut,
        uint amountIn,
        bool zeroForOne
    ) = abi.decode(data, (address, address, uint24, address, address, uint, bool));

    require(msg.sender == address(pool0), "not authorized");

    uint amountOut;
    if (zeroForOne) {
        amountOut = uint(-amount1);
    } else {
        amountOut = uint(-amount0);
    }

    uint buyBackAmount = _swap(tokenOut, tokenIn, fee1, amountOut);

    if (buyBackAmount >= amountIn) {
        uint profit = buyBackAmount - amountIn;
        IERC20(tokenIn).transfer(address(pool0), amountIn);
        IERC20(tokenIn).transfer(caller, profit);
    } else {
        uint loss = amountIn - buyBackAmount;
        IERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(caller, address(this), loss);
        IERC20(tokenIn).transfer(address(pool0), amountIn);
    }
}

function _swap(
    address tokenIn,
    address tokenOut,
    uint24 fee,
    uint amountIn
) private returns (uint amountOut) {
    IERC20(tokenIn).approve(address(router), amountIn);

    ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
        .ExactInputSingleParams({
            tokenIn: tokenIn,
            tokenOut: tokenOut,
            fee: fee,
            recipient: address(this),
            deadline: block.timestamp,
            amountIn: amountIn,
            amountOutMinimum: 0,
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
        });

    amountOut = router.exactInputSingle(params);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The reentrancy guard. A transaction cannot re-enter the pool mid-swap

refer to :  https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/error-codes